# Strange Cython Syntax

Tags: python, cython

I was looking through the quicktions fractions library and I found this cython syntax I've never seen before:

```
  an, ad = (<Fraction>a)._numerator, (<Fraction>a)._denominator
```

What does `(<Fractions>a)` represent? It seems like it's some sort of memory allocation. But, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It's a type cast.](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/language_basics.html#type-casting)

It assures Cython that the object really is a `Fraction` so that it can access the `_numerator` and `_denominator` attributes of the `cdef` type. Without the cast it can only use the generic Python lookup mechanisms to find attributes which doesn't allow you to access any non-`public` attributes of `cdef` types.

It doesn't do any checks that it is actually the correct type, so if you're not 100% sure that the object is actually a fraction then you should do `<Fraction?>` instead which does check.

Answer (score 4):

That is just the [Cython syntax for type casting](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/language_basics.html#type-casting). In this case, `a` is being casted to a `Fraction` type. The additional parentheses are necessary to signify that you want to cast `a` and the get the `_numerator` property of the casted value, not cast `a._numerator`.

Comment: This answer was 22 seconds quicker I think, so all things being equal accept this one :)

Comment: @DavidW Appreciate it :) Yours gives some extra information though so it's probably _correcter_.